# About python package structure - elements per module

Tags: python, package, structure

Is there any objective, strong argument against having a file for each group of correlated modules instead of heavily packaging them in a single module? For example, say I have a subpackage named `utils`, and one of the utilities it provides is regarding input and output of data. What I mean is if it's wrong to put big functions (with their important related subfunctions) in "private" modules and then call them via importing the main module `io`.

```
utils/
  io.py
  _pprint.py
  _ptable.py
```

Say `_pprint` is a big method that requires some other little sub-methods, then those would be in the `_pprint.py` module as well, because they're heavily correlated.

Basically, the issue is that I have a `io.py` module (and some others) with 20 functions that are a pain to read/scroll through to find some specific ones I want to change. I would like to have (as an example) an `io` module that can be called via `import package.io` and then, inside `io.py`, it imports the other modules that are related to I/O, or something like that (maybe I would need to do this with subpackages instead, to use more `__init__.py`'s).

Comment: No, as long as it is still navigable there is nothing wrong with having a bunch of independent files. The only thing to remember is imports are seen from the perspective of the main script so a script in `dir1 -> dir2 -> script` would need to import a script in `dir1 -> dir2 -> dir3 -> script` as `import dir1.dir2.dir3.script` when ran from main, but will import as `import dir3.script` when ran from the script in testing. Also each subfolder needs a `__init__.py` in it.

Comment: @tgikal Thank you. Don't be afraid to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as long as it is still navigable, there is nothing wrong with having a bunch of independent files.

As to your question about having a "io module that can be called via import package.io" the way to do this easily is have the directory structured:

```
packages -> io -> __init__.py
```

In the __init__.py, have the imports for the submodules:

__init__.py:

```
from packages.io import submodule
```

- When `import packages.io` is called, the submodules will be attributes
  of packages.io.
- Remember the __init__.py imports need to be from the main script's
  perspective.

Running this should give you a layout of directories and files to play with:

```
import os

os.makedirs("./packages/io")
with open("./main.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write("import packages.io as io\n")
    f.write("io.module1.call()\n")
    f.write("io.module2.call()\n")

with open("./packages/io/__init__.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write("from packages.io import module1\n")
    f.write("from packages.io import module2\n")

with open("./packages/io/module1.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write("def call():\n")
    f.write("\tprint('Module 1 called')")

with open("./packages/io/module2.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write("def call():\n")
    f.write("\tprint('Module 2 called')")
```